# Set anchor point in UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to perform transform animation in `UICollectionViewLayout`. Well that is achieved easily but I can't find way to set the `anchorPoint` of `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`. I want to perform door opening and closing animation while collection view item is inserted

```
-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [super initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];
    attributes.alpha = 1.0;
    CGFloat progress = 0.0;
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform.m34 = -1.0/500.0;
    CGFloat angle = (1 - progress) * M_PI_2;

    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 0, 1, 0  );
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView    cellForItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];
    cell.hidden = YES;

    attributes.transform3D = transform;
    return attributes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an `anchorPoint` attribute in `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`, so you'll have to subclass it, add a property for `anchorPoint` and use the `applyLayoutAttributes` on `UICollectionViewCell` to set the `anchorPoint` value on the cell.